# JSON how to remove &#x27; letters of the string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to remove `&#x27;` from my string. How to do that? I'm using ajax with JSON.
My code looks like this:

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <p id="testHTML"></p>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            setInterval(function() {
                $.getJSON("IOCounter.html", function(data) {
                    $('#testHTML').text(data.testHTML);
                });
            }, 2000); //Refreshrate in ms
        });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Inside testHTML, I get the string "HelloWorld" from IOCounter.html but when I display it inside index.html I get:

```
&#x27;HelloWorld&#x27;
```

Now I just want to remove `&#x27;` to get only HelloWorld. What do I have to do?

Comment: The string returned is `html` encoded. To decode, use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434

Comment: I've seen this post before, but I cant get where to place htmlDecode in my own code and how to use it with p tag... Sorry I'm very new into coding with html and javascript

Comment: Just decode it before adding the element. Seeing your code, it seems, you would need to decode `data.testHTML` and then set it to `#testHTML`. e.g. ```$('#testHTML').text(htmlDecode(data.testHTML));``` . Just make sure `htmlDecode` function is defined and available.

Comment: ok thank you so far, my HTML decodes it now, but the refresh function doesnt work

Comment: It should work. Since you are receiving the `data` once, then the request must also be working fine. If not, then chain your getJSON with a `.fail()` and add a callback to check the `error`.

Comment: Added the solution to an answer so that it helps others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string returned is HTML encoded. To get a plain text string, it needs to be decoded.

[DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) (supported in most browsers) can be used to decode the string as follows:

```
function htmlDecode(str) {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
    return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}
```

Using this, you can decode the string and then set it to `#textHTML`.

```
$.getJSON("IOCounter.html", function(data) {
    $('#testHTML').text(htmlDecode(data.testHTML));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Homemade solution

You can decode the Unicode characters with this function :

```js
export const unicodeDecode = (text: string) => {
  const decoded = text.replace(/&#x([0-9a-f]+);/gi, (_, code) =>
    String.fromCharCode(parseInt(code, 16))
  );
  return decoded;
};
```

It will replace all `#...;` like `&#x27;` by the Unicode characters.

In the callback function of replace, we take the code (for `&#x27;` its `27`) and we replace it by its UTF value using `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(code, 16))`

### Node.JS solution

Alternatively, in a Node.js application, you can use [node-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser) !

Found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68653286/12472736)

```js
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';

const root = parse('<ul id="list"><li>Hello World</li></ul>');
console.log(root.querySelector('#list'));
```

### DOM Solution

```
function htmlDecode(str) {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
    return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}
```

([from the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63537220/12472736))

**But in all case, the homemade solution will work.**