# How to use DOMParser in next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, next.js, domparser

I want manipulate an html string, in vanillaJS I would do it something like this:

```
  let HTMLString = '<p>hello</p>
                            <style> 
                             p{
                               color:black
                              }
                            <p>world</p>
                             '
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(HTMLString, "text/html");
    doc.querySelectorAll('style').forEach(item => item.remove())
```

this works in react aswell, but i believe since next compiles server side it just throws `DOMParser is not defined`, i've tried packages like `html-react-parser`, they just parse the html into react elements and offer very limited functionality after that, my last resort is using regex for this, but i've that's not a good idea.

any help in this would be good, thanks

Comment: does this question ([Trying to use the DOMParser with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js)) address your question?

Comment: i don't believe we can use those packages in React/Next

Comment: Hi, you can do that in a "useEffect" call, as useEffect is only called client-side.

Comment: Are you trying to run this code on the server-side (inside `getStaticProps`/`getSeverSideProps`)?

Answer (score 6):

you may try node-html-parser component that I used for the similar reason in my next.js project:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser

The idea is to use it server side in your getStaticProps() function like this:

```
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';

const root = parse('<ul id="list"><li>Hello World</li></ul>');
console.log(root.querySelector('#list'));
```

As you can see you can traverse through this virtually generated dom using the standard ES6 query selectors, and there are also many more options so I found this one very powerful.